# Renaming install.php for security?

Tags: security, installation

A few years ago I was reading some blogs on how to harden your WP site, and one of the things suggested was to rename your install.php file so that someone couldn't re-install a new WP site over top of the current one.

It appears that when you update WP now the install.php file is put back. I've been trying to google whether this step is still necessary, but haven't found anything useful.

Any hard evidence this is still a good thing to implement? Or can I safely take this off my checklist of things to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is a good step to take in hardening the site.  I would not recommend interfering directly with the files from WordPress for the exact reason your describe: updates will overwrite it.

Two options I would recommend:

- Use a hardening plug-in to help you do this
- Add a rule to .htaccess to prevent people from accessing the file

In the `wp-admin` folder add this to `.htaccess`:

`<Files install.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>`

Comment: Doing Option #2 breaks the site for me: Forbidden; You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server.

Comment: I'll take a look at it later today.  You might still consider a hardening plug-in like Securi.